# Internal Error NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have some promises chained and only a promise throw a internal error,
but i dont know why. Does anyone know this error?:
(Give me just clues for this error, i tried with Chrome debugger and others stuffs)

```js
facebook.GetDiscordPosts(5) //5 posts default
    .then(posts => TournamentsFilter(posts))
    .then(tournaments => ToDataFile(tournaments))
    //.then(pPosts => discord.PostTournament(pPosts)) <-- Error!
    .then(r => console.log("Done!"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

discord.js code

```js
'use strict';
const config = require("./config.json");
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const { discord : { token, prefix, channelTarget, webhookID, webhookToken, roleid } } = config;

async function PostTournament (pPosts) {
    try {
        let discordClient = new Discord.Client();
        for (let pPost of pPosts) {
                let client = new Discord.WebhookClient(webhookID, webhookToken);
                client.name = "Network of Darkness - Admin";
                let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                                    .setTitle("New Tournament")
                                    .setURL(pPost.link)
                                    .setImage(pPost.picture)
                                    .setDescription(pPost.message)
                                    .setColor("b23aee");
                await client.send(`:loudspeaker: <@&${roleid}>`, embed);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    
}

module.exports.PostTournament = async function (pPosts) {
PostTournament(pPosts)
.catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Full error code:

```js
internal/process/warning.js:130
      warning.name = String(type || 'Warning');
                     ^

TypeError: String is not a function
    at process.emitWarning (internal/process/warning.js:130:22)
    at emitWarning (internal/process/promises.js:92:15)
    at emitPendingUnhandledRejections (internal/process/promises.js:109:11)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:124:9)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

[Relationated Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440666/promises-resolved-in-disorder-and-errors)

Comment: isn't this just the same error `warning.name = String(type || 'Warning');` as the last question?

Comment: yes, but here i show full code in the promise and the question have other orientation

Comment: but still doesn't show why `String` has been overwritten - presumably by some code of yours - somewhere in your code, add `console.log(String+'')` - if it doesn't output `function String() { [native code] }` then you may get a clue with what is output as to what is happening

Comment: you realise `module.exports.PostTournament = async function (pPosts) {
PostTournament(pPosts)
.catch(err => console.log(err))
}` means that you won't be `await`ing anything, right? I'd change that to `module.exports.PostTournament = PostTournament`

Comment: Check my answer @JaromandaX Ty for all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was this:

```js
let postElement = { 
                id:String = post.id,
                link:String = post.permalink_url,
                message:String = post.message,
                picture:String = post.full_picture
            }
```

Corrected:

```js
let postElement = { 
                id : post.id,
                link : post.permalink_url,
                message : post.message,
                picture : post.full_picture
            }
```

Ty @Jaromanda X

Comment: Wow. I'm surprised the original code even executed. I mean without a parsing error.  Can't get my head around that.